# sublime text - eclipse App Explorer equivalent

Tags: eclipse, sublimetext2

Hi I wondering if there is the equivalent to an App Explorer in Sublime Text 2.
When using eclipse, I use the App Explorer panel to search by file name.

I have a file naming convention that helps me find files by there functionality within the system.
So say I want to list all files relating to the registration process. I search for "regis" via the App Explorer and get a nice list of the relevant files. This filtered list is available all the time until I search again.

I can use Sublime Text's cmd+p but prefer the above as I can see the folder hierarchy etc.
In essence it is merely a file name filter on the folder list.

Are there any plugins that may give me something similar.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I can tell nothing like this has been implemented in Sublime Text 2. I would suggest opening an issue at [Sublime's UserEcho forum](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/).

In the meantime:

- Typing "regis" into Sublime's 'GoTo Anything' panel *will* bring up the files you're looking for, and show you their paths (I realize this doesn't help you with visualizing the hierarchy, but that's as close as it gets).
- I use a package called [SyncedSideBar](https://github.com/sobstel/SyncedSideBar) - this will at least show you a visual representation of the folder hierarchy in the sidebar, for the **open** file, if it's added to the project.
- The [GoTo Folder](https://github.com/freewizard/SublimeGotoFolder) package by freewizard may do something similar to what you're looking for, but I had trouble getting it to work. Maybe you'll have more success.

Good luck!

Comment: All good suggestions Sara, thanks for you help. After playing around with sublime for a bit, I've realized I should just change my workflow. The ability to open more than one instance will also help.